# How do I add several traces to a single plot?

Tags: r, plotly, purrr, r-plotly

I would like to add y axis traces to plotly object using map from purrr package. But instead of adding new traces to the existing plot, it creates individual plots for each trace. See:

```
library(purrr)
library(plotly)

data("iris")

p = plot_ly(iris, type = "bar")
xaxis = ~Species
map(c(~Sepal.Length, ~Sepal.Width, ~Petal.Length, ~Petal.Width), ~add_trace(p, x = xaxis, y = .x))
```

Is there a way to remedy this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` is the wrong function for this because it iteratively applies the same function to different arguments in turn, by definition.

What you want to do is different: you want to *aggregate* a result over different arguments, by applying a given operation on the current aggregate and the next argument. In functional programming terminology, this is known as a *reduction*, and purrr provides the function [`reduce`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/reduce.html) for it.

```
trace_vars = c(~Sepal.Length, ~Sepal.Width, ~Petal.Length, ~Petal.Width)
result = reduce(trace_vars, ~ add_trace(.x, x = xaxis, y = .y), .init = p)
```

This is effectively the same as

```
add_trace(
  add_trace(
    …,
    x = xaxis, y = ~Sepal.Width
  ),
  x = xaxis, y = ~Sepal.Length
)
```

You can invert the direction via `reduce`’s `.dir` argument.

To include names, use `reduce2` with an adapted formula. Unfortunately extracting the names from the formulas is a bit annoying:

```
trace_names = map_chr(trace_vars, ~ as.character(.x[[2L]]))

result = reduce2(
    trace_vars, trace_names,
    ~ add_trace(..1, x = xaxis, y = ..2, name = ..3),
    .init = p
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Konrad! One follow-up question, if I could. How to add names to traces? I have tried reduce2 names vector `names = c("Sepal length", "Sepal width", "Petal length", "Petal width")` to `name` argument in add_trace but so far no luck.